# Will dropping transient journals affect other users?

Tags: sql, teradata

Teradata SQL Assistant fails to create a new table due to the error "No more room in database DBC".  I figured out that the Transient Journal is taking up too much space.

I, personally, have no need for the journal.  Can I drop the journal without consequence to other users? `modify database xxx as drop default journal table;`

Comment: yes go-ahead. Keep in mind that you can recover it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you confusing the transient journal with a permanent journal on a table?

Transient Journal  will use all of the free space on the system (TD 13.x and maybe TD 12) to maintain the ability to rollback the changes being made for one or more transactions on the system. If there are no transactions that require journaling there is not transient journal space being consumed. Keep in mind that certain operations like loading an empty table may not require a transient journal because the rollback state would be an empty table.

If you run out of free space for the transient journal the error message still reports that the database DBC is at fault for running out of space even though Teradata is consuming all the free space on the system for the transient journal.

A permanent journal on the other hand is what you seem to be dropping with that DDL statement. You may remove the permanent journal if you are certain that it will not have a negative impact on your on environment and recovery operations for either your applications, ETL streams, and/or disaster recovery plans.